# Custom Image Picker for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-controls, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have my own collectionView in my app. I don't want to use the default UIImagePicker for my app & I want to implement Image Picker with my collection View.

Can anyone tell me how to implement custom selecting Album View and after select the Album, How to implement custom View to view all the images in that album.

Sorry if this is very easy question.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=imagepickercontroller

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/snimagepicker see this custom control

Comment: https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController This might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with help of ALASSETS. You can find documentation on it below.
**https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class**

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

                  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
          if (asset)
          {  
               NSLog(@"%@",asset);  

              NSLog(@".. do something with the asset");    
          }
      }
      ];
 }

                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
      {
          // User did not allow access to library
         // .. handle error 
      }
      ] ;
```

**If you want to populate it to collection view you need to create a custom cell having Alasset type variable**.